# System.FormatException thrown upon clicking a button, but the program opens after clicking OK - WPF

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, wpf

I input name, generic password and password and when I click on "Log in" I get a ***System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct*** format. However, after clicking **Ok** the Window that I intended to get opened, gets opened. How do I get rid of the exception. The exception states that the error is thrown in this pile of code:

```
`private void ShowEmployeeRank1()
        {
            // use a try-catch, in case we run into an
            // error while digging into the database
            try
            {
                // create a query and select everything from the EmployeeRankq table
                string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1";

                // the SqlDataAdapter can be imagined like an
                // Interface to make tables usable by C# objects

                // create a connection to the database and run the query
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection);

                // use the sqlDataAdapter
                using (sqlDataAdapter)
                {
                    // create a new DataTable that allows us
                    // to store data from tables within objects
                    DataTable employeeRank1Table = new DataTable();

                    // fill the sqlDataAdapter with all the
                    // information from the query(from the employeeRank1Table)
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(employeeRank1Table);

                    // set the content of the employeeRank1List
                    // to be "Name" from the table "EmployeeRank1"
                    employeeRank1List.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

                    // set the value of a specific item
                    // of listEmployeeRank1 to be "Id" from "EmployeeRank1" table
                    employeeRank1List.SelectedValuePath = "Id";

                    // set the content in the employeeRank1List to be the
                    // content of the EmployeeRank1 table in a DefaultView mode
                    employeeRank1List.ItemsSource = employeeRank1Table.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // show what is the error
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And more specificaly this line of code: `employeeRank1List.ItemsSource = employeeRank1Table.DefaultView;`

Comment: This fixed the Exception, but now the records that I have in my listbox for EmployeeRank1 table are no longer visible.

Comment: Because the advice made no sense. Remove ToString. For your question, try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried just setting the datatable as the source and not the defaultview? For example: `employeeRank1List.ItemsSource = employeeRank1Table;`; you're not doing any filtering, why would you use a defaultview? Also what type of object is `employeeRank1List`?

Comment: @zaggler Just tried it, throws an error - they are of different types. In fact, I am doing filtering, I am trying to show a certain column of my table, not all of it. employeeRank1List is a listBox.

Comment: @zaimov why type of control is `employeeRank1List`?

Comment: @zaggler It is a listBox.

Comment: Perhaps tell us what it exactly means when you "*click on "Log in"*" - there is nothing like that in your question. Assigning an collection to a ItemsSource property does not produce a FormatException.

Comment: Log in is a button and when clicked, seeks through the EmployeeRank1 table and seeks if there is a match between the name, generic password and password given as an input and the ones that exist in the table itself.

Comment: The query may not be executed before the ItemsSource assignment is made. Then you get an exception from some invalid data in your db.

Comment: Try `employeeRank1List.ItemsSource = employeeRank1Table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r["Name"]).ToList();` and remove the `.path` properties you set, does that help?

Comment: And is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Do we know your data? Maybe there is some useful information in the InnerException(s).

Comment: @zaggler The exception is gone, but the records in the listbox are no longer visible.

Comment: That is because DefaultView is still the correct approach, despite what people are telling you.

Comment: What bugs me is that I have the exact same method but for my two other tables, which are EmployeeRank2 and EmplloyeeRank3, and they work perfectly fine. No exceptions whatsover.

Comment: What does your xaml look like for this? You really should be looking into mvvm, this isn't a route I would take.

Comment: @Clemens am I missing something?

Comment: @Clemens thanks, I need to focus more on comments :), I'm ready for the weekend already it seems...

Comment: I am really lost at this point.

Comment: Did you not check the InnerException(s) of the FormatException?

Comment: Don't know how to do that, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Google it. The exception should make the Visual Studio debugger break when it occurs. Then check the fields of the exception object.